# Can't build zeromq 3.2 stable in osx 10.8.2

Tags: macos, message-queue, zeromq

./configure --with-pgm
make

I got same error:

```
Making all in foreign/openpgm
Making all in build-staging/openpgm/pgm
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"OpenPGM\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"openpgm\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"5.1.118\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"OpenPGM\ 5.1.118\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"openpgm-dev@googlegroups.com\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H=1 -DHAVE_ALLOCA=1 -DHAVE_ARPA_INET_H=1 -DHAVE_FCNTL_H=1 -DHAVE_FLOAT_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -DHAVE_LOCALE_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H=1 -DHAVE_STDDEF_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIMEB_H=1 -DHAVE_SYSLOG_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_WCHAR_H=1 -DHAVE__BOOL=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_GETPAGESIZE=1 -DHAVE_MMAP=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_REALLOC=1 -DHAVE_DECL_STRERROR_R=1 -DHAVE_STRERROR_R=1 -DHAVE_ATEXIT=1 -DHAVE_FLOOR=1 -DHAVE_FTIME=1 -DHAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR=1 -DHAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=1 -DHAVE_GETHOSTNAME=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_INET_NTOA=1 -DHAVE_MEMMOVE=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -DHAVE_REGCOMP=1 -DHAVE_SELECT=1 -DHAVE_SETENV=1 -DHAVE_SETLOCALE=1 -DHAVE_SOCKET=1 -DHAVE_SQRT=1 -DHAVE_STPCPY=1 -DHAVE_STRCASECMP=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_STRERROR=1 -DHAVE_STRNCASECMP=1 -DHAVE_STRPBRK=1 -DHAVE_STRRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRSTR=1 -DHAVE_STRTOL=1 -DHAVE_STRTOUL=1 -DHAVE_STRTOULL=1 -I.    -I./include -DCONFIG_16BIT_CHECKSUM -DCONFIG_GALOIS_MUL_LUT -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE='"pgm"' -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DCONFIG_HAVE_GETNETENT -DCONFIG_HAVE_ISO_VARARGS -DCONFIG_HAVE_GNUC_VARARGS -DCONFIG_HAVE_ALLOCA_H -DCONFIG_HAVE_BACKTRACE -DCONFIG_HAVE_PSELECT -DCONFIG_HAVE_POLL -DCONFIG_HAVE_GETIFADDRS -DCONFIG_HAVE_IFR_NETMASK -DCONFIG_HAVE_MCAST_JOIN -DCONFIG_HAVE_IP_MREQN -DCONFIG_HAVE_SPRINTF_GROUPING -DCONFIG_HAVE_VASPRINTF -DCONFIG_HAVE_DSO_VISIBILITY -DCONFIG_BIND_INADDR_ANY -DCONFIG_HOST_ORDER_IP_LEN -DCONFIG_HOST_ORDER_IP_OFF -DCONFIG_TICKET_SPINLOCK -DCONFIG_DUMB_RWSPINLOCK -MT libpgm_noinst_la-thread.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libpgm_noinst_la-thread.Tpo -c -o libpgm_noinst_la-thread.lo `test -f 'thread.c' || echo './'`thread.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"OpenPGM\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"openpgm\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"5.1.118\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"OpenPGM 5.1.118\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"openpgm-dev@googlegroups.com\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H=1 -DHAVE_ALLOCA=1 -DHAVE_ARPA_INET_H=1 -DHAVE_FCNTL_H=1 -DHAVE_FLOAT_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_LIMITS_H=1 -DHAVE_LOCALE_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H=1 -DHAVE_STDDEF_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIMEB_H=1 -DHAVE_SYSLOG_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_WCHAR_H=1 -DHAVE__BOOL=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_GETPAGESIZE=1 -DHAVE_MMAP=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_REALLOC=1 -DHAVE_DECL_STRERROR_R=1 -DHAVE_STRERROR_R=1 -DHAVE_ATEXIT=1 -DHAVE_FLOOR=1 -DHAVE_FTIME=1 -DHAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR=1 -DHAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=1 -DHAVE_GETHOSTNAME=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_INET_NTOA=1 -DHAVE_MEMMOVE=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -DHAVE_REGCOMP=1 -DHAVE_SELECT=1 -DHAVE_SETENV=1 -DHAVE_SETLOCALE=1 -DHAVE_SOCKET=1 -DHAVE_SQRT=1 -DHAVE_STPCPY=1 -DHAVE_STRCASECMP=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_STRERROR=1 -DHAVE_STRNCASECMP=1 -DHAVE_STRPBRK=1 -DHAVE_STRRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRSTR=1 -DHAVE_STRTOL=1 -DHAVE_STRTOUL=1 -DHAVE_STRTOULL=1 -I. -I./include -DCONFIG_16BIT_CHECKSUM -DCONFIG_GALOIS_MUL_LUT -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=\"pgm\" -fvisibility=hidden -D_REENTRANT -DCONFIG_HAVE_GETNETENT -DCONFIG_HAVE_ISO_VARARGS -DCONFIG_HAVE_GNUC_VARARGS -DCONFIG_HAVE_ALLOCA_H -DCONFIG_HAVE_BACKTRACE -DCONFIG_HAVE_PSELECT -DCONFIG_HAVE_POLL -DCONFIG_HAVE_GETIFADDRS -DCONFIG_HAVE_IFR_NETMASK -DCONFIG_HAVE_MCAST_JOIN -DCONFIG_HAVE_IP_MREQN -DCONFIG_HAVE_SPRINTF_GROUPING -DCONFIG_HAVE_VASPRINTF -DCONFIG_HAVE_DSO_VISIBILITY -DCONFIG_BIND_INADDR_ANY -DCONFIG_HOST_ORDER_IP_LEN -DCONFIG_HOST_ORDER_IP_OFF -DCONFIG_TICKET_SPINLOCK -DCONFIG_DUMB_RWSPINLOCK -MT libpgm_noinst_la-thread.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libpgm_noinst_la-thread.Tpo -c thread.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/libpgm_noinst_la-thread.o
In file included from ./include/impl/sockaddr.h:38,
             from ./include/impl/notify.h:46,
             from ./include/impl/framework.h:66,
             from thread.c:23:
./include/pgm/in.h:34: error: redefinition of ‘struct group_req’
./include/pgm/in.h:40: error: redefinition of ‘struct group_source_req’
make[2]: *** [libpgm_noinst_la-thread.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

just like :
https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-454

Who knows how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, by doing this:

```
cd foreign/openpgm/
wget http://openpgm.googlecode.com/files/libpgm-5.2.122~dfsg.tar.gz
cd ../..
./configure --with-pgm=libpgm-5.2.122~dfsg
make
```